# How to receive detailed reputation from SEDE?

Tags: stackexchange-api, dataexplorer

Using the api it is possible to receive the detailed user reputation like this:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#ids=1719510&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true
```

How is it possible to make it on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)?

Comment: I believe this belongs on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

SEDE doesn't provide such information and I guess this is because it is updated weekly; the API is real-time, though.

You can get the reputation of the user, however, it's in the `Users` table. You can fetch it by using something like this:

```
SELECT Reputation
FROM Users
WHERE id=##UserId##
```

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1166122/stack-overflow-question-id-59128686?UserId=11786778) it is live!

*Note*: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391786) is actually not as accurate as the API. It misses events like reputation reversal, although it includes the most important ones.